# Sample from a Vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector with 48 numbers in it and I need to randomly select 26 numbers from this vector without replacement and store them in a vector.  I also need to store the remaining 22 numbers in a separate vector.  I know how to randomly pick the 26 numbers without replacement and store them, but I am having difficulties trying to find the 22 numbers that were left over.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show some of your work before asking for assistance. Sample code or a reproducible example will not only help you get a quicker response, it will also help those asking similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
v <- 1:48
chosen <- sample(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(26, 22)))
v[chosen] #one set
v[!chosen] #its complement
```

Comment: @H Good point. I sometimes forget just how vectorized R's built-in functions tend to be.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a random sample of the *indicies* and take the first 26. The remaining 22 are your "left-overs".

```
i <- sample(1:48)
x1 <- x[i[1:26]]  # main sample
x2 <- x[i[27:48]] # left-overs
```

Comment: Nice (+1). This should be the accepted answer, though you doubtless meant `x[i[1:26]]`

Comment: I did indeed. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setdiff` to get the remaining numbers.

```
total_numbers <- 1:48
first_set <- sample(total_numbers, 26)
remaining_set <- setdiff(total_numbers, first_set)
```

I am assuming here that you have unique numbers in `total_numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the syntax `%in%` like so:

```
numbers1 <- sample(x, 26, replacement = false)
numbers2 <- x[!which(x %in% numbers1)]
```